# I have already installed webdriver_manager but python can't find the module

Tags: python, windows, selenium

This is from my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\tques\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

I have tried both instances of the "driver" variable, both independently and together but I always get this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'"

I've already tried uninstalling selenium and webdriver_manager, then reinstalling them, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

find the file path ware webdriver_manager is installed, then add

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<webdriver_manager path>)
```

before

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

Comment: I tried that (see below) but the problem persists. 
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\tques\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\webdriver_manager")
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a driver to the PATH? - [HOW TO DO THIS](https://developers.refinitiv.com/sites/default/files/How%20To%20Add%20ChromeDriver%20To%20System%20Variables_0.pdf)

And then do as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to have to manually update the driver every time. From what I've read, using webdriver_manager should automate the process. If I can't get it to work, I'll have to write an automation script myself

Comment: Be careful with keeping your driver always up-to-date, as it could potentially cause future issues. Better to use the static driver and then do migration IF this is essential + testings

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver<br> 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).